# Is 'unassumingly' a real word?

Tags: adverbs, is-it-a-word, derivational-morphology

So I'm trying to say 'in a way that doesn't draw attention from others'. Is 'unassumingly' right word for that or what kind of adverb should I use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried but online dictionaries didn't help at all. Maybe I should go find an actual book…

Comment: @annnna: There's no need to go to any *specific* book. Just [search for "**unassumingly**" in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22unassumingly%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Even if "About 17,100 results" is wildly inaccurate (I've no idea), that should be proof enough that the word exists.

Comment: [AHDEL & Wordnet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unassumingly) together provide the definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's a real word.

Example: "*You felt that it was him that quietly and **unassumingly** kept things together as both Pete Townsend and Roger Daltry seemed quite volatile characters."*

[unassuming. Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 20 January 2015.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unassuming?q=unassumingly#unassuming__5)

Comment: No problem @annnna. :)

Comment: Unassumingly: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=unassumingly&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cunassumingly%3B%2Cc0